# C++: Does it cause any problems if I include multiple header files, if both have #include <string>?

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to write my own little "game", that's why I started programming itself. However, using multiple header files for declaring multiple classes used by separate .cpps brought me to a question: does it cause any harm later on if I `#include <string>` into every one of them, and include multiple of these headers into a single .cpp?
An example:

```
//a.cpp
#include "x.h"
#include "y.h"
int main(){blablabla}

//x.h
#ifndef XCLASS_H #define XCLASS_H
#include <string>
class xclass{std::string xstring;};
#endif

//y.h
#ifndef YCLASS_H #define YCLASS_H
#include <string>
class yclass{std::string ystring;};
#endif
```

As I know, both would include  to a.cpp. When I tried, the program ran fine and without any errors. I'm using Visual Studio 2012. Will this cause problems on other computers, and if so, how can I avoid them?

Comment: Nope. They have header guards, specifically [pragma once](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once).

Comment: Note that what BWG said is only valid for header files which have guards like pragmatic once, as all the standard headers do. If you want (or have) to do this with your own headers, you have to supply the guards.

Comment: Do not use `#pragma once` as it is non-standard thing.

Comment: @doc Why does the stanard `string` header use it?

Comment: @bwg: An implementation file can do whatever dirty thing. However `#pragma once` is not a dirty thing. I recommend using it only, and not include guards. Chances of saving work that way are, I gather, at 99.9% or higher. And chances of wasting work with include guards, ditto.

Comment: @BWG because you use MS library and MS provides support for `#pragma once`. But other compilers may not give you such support, so if you want to make **your** code portable avoid `#pragma once`.

Comment: @BWG: The standard doesn't specify that the header use it, since it's non-standard (as are all pragmas, by definition). A particular implementation might use it, if it's only intended for compilers that support it.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf yes it's not dirty, but it's not standard. It's not supported by IBM compilers, GCC had it on deprecated list etc.

Comment: @doc so from what you say, #pragma once is supported by Microsoft and will run well on their systems, but may not work on others?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Well, it's not like traditional guards are that much work. Pragma once is one line, and traditional ones are like 3 lines.

Comment: @KvB right. Actually it will work with many other compilers, but there are compilers that don't support it and in others support may be dropped (like it was in GCC).

Comment: @doc I love when people start an argument and you can actually learn more than what you've asked for. So nice to see such. I guess i'll stay at Stackoverflow.
Thanks for all your [everyone's] help!

Comment: @KvB _"so from what you say, #pragma once is supported by Microsoft and will run well on their systems, but may not work on others?"_ More or less yes. For writing portable solutions, I'd recommend the _good old header guards_ preferably over `#pragma once`.

Comment: @BWG: i think you're mistaking me for KvB. anyway, there are compilers that don't really support C++, and AIX is on that list. it's a good idea to avoid them, and it's not a good idea to let them guide or at all influence your C++ coding. i.e. `#pragma once` will save you much work, unless you *choose* to do mud-wrestling.

Comment: @doc `#pragma once` was briefly deprecated in GCC 3.2 because it was non-standard and poorly implemented, but was later [undeprecated](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11569#c12) because it is a _de facto_ standard and the implementation was fixed.  There are **no** plans to drop support from GCC.

Comment: @piedar I have written it in past tense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include a standard header however many times you want in each translation unit.

Usually subsequent inclusions after the first one will have no effect.

One exception is the `<assert.h>` header, which defines the `assert` macro. This header can define `assert` differently, depending on the symbol `NDEBUG`, each time that it’s included. Since that’s a bit unusual the standard points it out explicitly.

---

Standardese:

**C++11 §17.6.22/2** [using.headers]**:**

> **”** A translation unit may include library headers in any order (Clause 2). Each may be included more than
>   once, with no effect different from being included exactly once, except that the effect of including either
>   `<cassert>` or `<assert.h>` depends each time on the lexically current definition of `NDEBUG`.